# Transparency node artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I was using the Transparent BSDF node on a mesh, but even when I set it to full transparency there are some strange black areas that refuse to disappear. They change somewhat with the camera angle.

[image: The problem described]

How do I get rid of these artifacts? I'm using Blender v2.79b.